# localStorage Array Objects - How to check is Object Key Value exists

Tags: arrays, jscript

How would i check to see if the ID exists within the localStorage object key array

i am currenty using this and it does not work

```
if (favorites.includes(theid)) { alert('You Allready Added this Listing'); }
```

Also how do i pull the indivdual object array apart into ID , image , title
to make varibles

Thank you

Below is the Full Code

```
function checkfave (theid) {

// get favorites from local storage or empty array
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
var theimage = $('#theimage'+theid).attr('src');
var thetitle = $('#thetitle'+theid).text();

if (localStorage.getItem('favorites') != null) {
    if (favorites.includes(theid)) { alert('You Allready Added this Listing'); }
}
            
    favorites.push({ID:theid,IMAGE:theimage,TITLE:thetitle});
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));

    alert('You Just Added Listing '+theid+' To Your Favorites');


    //Loop through the Favorites List and display in console (HIDDEN)
    console.clear();

        for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) { 
            console.log('ID= '+favorites[i].ID+'  IMAGE='+favorites[i].IMAGE+'  TITLE='+favorites[i].TITLE);
        }//for loop
                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you parse json using `JSON.parse`, a javascript object is created.  You can access keys in javascript objects by simply using the bracket notation:

```
object[key] = value
```

If a key is not defined in an object, when you request the key you will get `undefined`.  `undefined` is equivalent to `false` when evaluating an if clause so you can simply use

```
if (favorites[theid]) { alert('You Allready Added this Listing'); }
```

Comment: Ok, il try that, thank you - Unfortunatly i get the error -

Uncaught ReferenceError: ID is not defined
using if (favorites[ID].includes(theid))

and the error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') 

when using if (favorites[theid].includes(theid))

But i imagine that i can pull the array apart this way as you suggested.

Comment: Two things: (1) you must define a string variable named "ID" if you are going to reference it as a key (I.E. `var ID = "myIdString"`).  (2) you do not need `includes` at all.  Whatever string key is being used to store the ID (or a variable assigned to that string key) should be used directly inside the brackets

Comment: The Values have been added into the Key Favourites. its just accessing them in struggling with i can console.log them thats fine. But checking if theid exists within the array of the 5 keys input is what im struggling with. i am currently trying a for loop with a defined varible. however im sure there must be a simpler way. but thanks for your help so far guys. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after the suggestions

My solution was to check within a for loop using favorites[i].ID == theid

The final code is below. i am very sure it could be done another way, But this works for now.

```
function checkfave (theid) {

var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
var theimage = $('#theimage'+theid).attr('src');
var thetitle = $('#thetitle'+theid).text();
var added=true;

    //Loop through the Favorites List and display in console (HIDDEN)  
    for (let i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) { 
            
    if ( favorites[i].ID == theid ) { alert('You allready Added Listing '+theid+' To Your Favorites'); var added=false; break; } else {var added=true;}
    
    }//for loop
        
                
        if (added===true) {
            favorites.push({ID:theid,IMAGE:theimage,TITLE:thetitle});
            localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
            alert('You Just Added Listing '+theid+' To Your Favorites');
        }


                                                
}
```